# How do I convert a python function/class/module object to a python code object

Tags: python, function, object, compilation

I have been looking around for some way to convert a function or class or module object in python to a python code object.

A few people accomplish this by doing `inspect.getsource()` and `compile()`, but the problem with this is that you are reading a potentially changed file, or if it was composed in the interactive python shell, you will just get an exception on `getsource`.

I was wondering if anyone else may have a solution to this problem, so it can look something like this:

```
import dis

def func(arg):
    x = 5
    arg = 3
    return x + arg

code_obj = function_to_code_obj(func)
dis.disassemble(code_obj)
```

and get the code object disassembly printed out like having created it using `compile()` or `parser.suite()`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a function you can use the `func_code` attribute:

```
import dis

def func(arg):
    x = 5
    arg = 3
    return x + arg

def function_to_code_obj(func):
    return func.func_code

code_obj = function_to_code_obj(func)
dis.disassemble(code_obj)
```

Comment: thanks, this should be good since the module code and class code is just run once... and I can just get the members after execution.